# Failed to call "pbmtextps" with execve() in C?

Tags: c, linux, exec, system

On my Linux terminal, when I type

```
pbmtextps cat | pamfile
```

and press enter.

It gives me the following output,

```
stdin:  PBM raw, 83 by 104
```

However, I am trying to call "pbmtextps" by using execve() in my main program. The following is the snippet of the program:

```
char* haha[] = {"pbmtextps","cat","|", "pamfile", NULL};
if(execve("pbmtextps",haha, NULL) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "NOT ok");
   }
else{
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", "OK");
}
```

After the program starts, program prints "Not ok". I run the program in the same directory on the same terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execve()` doesn't search the path for the program to run, so you need to give it a valid absolute or relative filename. It also doesn't use a shell, so that piping thing you're trying isn't going to work. The arguments are all passed directly to the program being executed.

It also doesn't return on success because there's nothing to return *to* so there's no point in printing a success message.

Comment: I also have another question. For the first argument, it gotta be the valid file path. But, If i wanna run built-in command, such as "ls", I have to pass "/bin/ls" as the first argument, and it works. But, there is no file named "ls" in the bin folder. Why does it work?